# How to constrain the resources a command line application can use on a linux webserver

Tags: php, linux, resources, webserver

This is the situation:

I have a (php/mysql) web application that does some pdf processing and thumbnail creation. This is done by using some 3rd party command line software on the server. Both kinds of processing consume a lot of resources, to the point of choking the server. I would like to limit the amount of resources these applications can use in order to enable the server to keep serving users without too much delay, because now when some heavy pdf is processed my users don't get any response.

Is it possible to constrain the amount of RAM and CPU an application can use (all processes combined)? Or is there another way to deal with these kinds of situations? How is this usually done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ulimit` to set resource limits. The "hard" limit is a maximum, operating-system-enforced limit of resources that cannot be increased once set. The "soft" limit is a recommended maximum that your process can change at will but cannot exceed the hard limit.

For example, to prevent `script.sh` from using more than 256MB of virtual memory:

```
ulimit -H -v $((2*1024*1024))
./script.sh
```

Build this into your PHP script that executes the process on the command line.

Comment: That looks like what I need in the memory department, thanks! How do I keep the CPU usage at bay?

Comment: `help ulimit` on a Linux machine bash prompt should tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I just assumed it was memory only, my mistake :)